# Unable to create a constant value of System.Object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I hit the `List<HickeryDickeryDock> dockMatches = (List<HickeryDickeryDock>)prtQuery.ToList();`line the error pops up "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'.  Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context".   I'ved returned a generic list object before so I'm probably over looking something as to why this is popping up with this one.

```
var prtQuery = (from p in db.PRTs
                join m in db.PROs on p.PRT_PRO_ID equals m.PRO_ID
                where p.PRT_PRO_ID != pro_id
                select new HickeryDickeryDock
                {
                    Name = m.PRO_FirstName + ' ' + m.PRO_LastName,
                    DisplayName = m.PRO_DisplayName,
                    Gender = m.PRO_Gender,
                    Age = prm.PRM_AgeStart >= p.PRT_AgeStart && prm.PRM_AgeStart <= p.PRT_AgeEnd ? 2 : 0,
                    Huckelberry = SqlFunctions.CharIndex("Huckelberry", p.PRT_Finnery) > 0 ? 2 : SqlFunctions.CharIndex("Spontaneous", prm.PRM_FINNERY) == 0 ? 0 : 2
                }).Take(100);


List<HickeryDickeryDock> dockMatches = (List<HickeryDickeryDock>)prtQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: What are the types of `p.PRT_PRO_ID` and `pro_id`? Can you reduce the code to remove the bits that *aren't* problematic? (For example, can you remove most of the properties in the projection?)

Comment: Edited to avoid so much horizontal scrolling - and note that you don't need to cast the result of `prtQuery.ToList()`; it's already `List<HickeryDickeryDock>`.

Comment: pro_id and prt_pro_id are nvarchar(128) fields that hold guid values. I actually removed a lot of the selection portion but I will try running it with just the ones I supplied to see if it works.

Comment: " and note that you don't need to cast the result of prtQuery.ToList(); it's already List<HickeryDickeryDock>".  I didn't have that initially but for the sake of just checking, I put it in because the error wasn't making sense to me and well I've seen stranger things happen in code.

Answer (score 0):

`Name = m.PRO_FirstName + ' ' + m.PRO_LastName`.  This was the line that was causing it to fail.  Once I removed `+ ' ' + m.PRO_LastName`, it worked.